# Why the Snackbar is re-shown in the below code when I am clearly setting the condition that should show the Snackbar to false in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-state, flutter2.0, flutter-sharedpreference

I have created a custom button widget in flutter called `BottomButton`. Since I feel that the implementation of the custom widget is not necessary for the question, I have simply omitted it.

```
    BottomButton(
        text: "Tap to Login",
        onPressed: () {
          errorMessage = LoginError.errorMessage;
          if (errorMessage != null) {
            SnackBar errorSnackBar = SnackBar(
                content: Text(
              LoginError.errorMessage,
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            ));
            setState() {
                errorMessage = null;
                LoginError.errorMessage = null;
            }
            Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(errorSnackBar);
          }
          loginWithEmailPassword();
        },
      )
```

In my application, after I call the Backend APi to authenticate a user, if there is an error authenticating the user I add it to `LoginError.errorMessage`. `LoginError` is a dart class and `errorMessage` is a **static** property of that class.

In the above code, what I am doing is upon tapping on my custom button widget to login the user, if there is an error, I am importing the error message I have added to the `LoginError.errorMessage` and displaying it on a `SnackBar`.

However if there is an error message, I reset the `LoginError.errorMessage` back to `null` and if the `LoginError.errorMessage` is `null`, I have written the code so that the `SnackBar` will not be shown. (The `SnackBar` is only shown if the `LoginError.errorMessage` is not `null` since I am doing an `if` check).

The current implementation shows error messages upon entering invalid credentials by the user. However if I enter correct credentials after entering the incorrect credentials and tapping on the   custom Button widget once, the user is logged in, but the `Invalid Credentials` error is also show n on the snack bar.

I can not figure out why it is showing that incorrect credentials error on the `Snackbar` when I am trying to login with valid credentials after typing incorrect credentials once.